# Wordpress Neve theme - main navigation css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using the WordPress theme Neve for a website https://demo.themeisle.com/neve/

I can't seem to find a way to override the css for main nav and sub nav (trying to change font color and hover effects).

The only changes I've managed to apply to navigation are for the active page and font size:

```
#nv-primary-navigation .current-menu-item > a {
color: #ffc72d!important; 
border-bottom: solid 2px #ffc72d!important;
```

}

```
.nav-menu-primary .menu-item {
font-size: 20px;
```

}

Would really appreciate it if someone could point in me the right direction in terms of how I can restyle the navigation. I've tried the following selectors without success:

```
#nv-primary-navigation .primary-menu-ul 
.sub-menu 
.caret
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you are looking for should be `.light-mode a:not(.button) {...}`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Apologies for the late reply